# CSS Transform div on not empty

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, knockout.js

On my site I have an aside that lets the user perform common tasks like adding an item. There are multiple steps (pages) and I want them to appear to slide in left to right using CSS.

I have tried using the empty tag and the visiblity tag to trigger the transition but it never happens.

```
.slideOnVisible:empty{
    height: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s linear;
       -moz-transition: height 0.5s linear;
        -ms-transition: height 0.5s linear;
         -o-transition: height 0.5s linear;
            transition: height 0.5s linear;

}
.slideOnVisible:not(:empty){
     height: 100%;
     -webkit-transition: height 0.5s linear;
        -moz-transition: height 0.5s linear;
         -ms-transition: height 0.5s linear;
          -o-transition: height 0.5s linear;
             transition: height 0.5s linear;

}
```

I don't need to transition the height property so if there is a better way please let me know.

I am using Bootstrap, LESS and ko.js

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p97wdqqm/1/

Comment: Whitespace counts as content. As you sure the div is empty?

Comment: When I use this in the console I get a match. $('.slideOnVisible:empty')

Comment: I am using the ko.js with binding to make sure it is empty. Based on their action, I then populate the property which will create the html in the div.

Comment: Added a fiddle to test

Comment: It is updated now. The only css in it is the transition css above.

Comment: What is the height supposed to be 100% of? If I apply some height to the body, the fiddle works as (I presume) you wanted. https://jsfiddle.net/p97wdqqm/2/

Comment: Ahhh awesome! And to make it have a slide right to left effect, I would have to do what you did for the height but for the width?

Comment: I was just trying a solution that was supposed to work and then I would tweak it as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you want something like this.

```js
var DemoModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.obsProperty = ko.observable(null);

  self.toggleObsProperty = function() {
    if (self.obsProperty() === null) {
      self.obsProperty({
        id: 1
      });
    } else {
      self.obsProperty(null);
    }
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(new DemoModel());
```

```css
.slideOnVisible {      /* initial state */
  height: 2em;  
  width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap; /* or it would wrap during the transition */
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: width 2.5s linear;
     -moz-transition: width 2.5s linear;
      -ms-transition: width 2.5s linear;
       -o-transition: width 2.5s linear;
          transition: width 2.5s linear;
}

.slideOnVisible:not(:empty) {
  width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<html>

<body id="main">
  <div class="slideOnVisible" data-bind="with: obsProperty">
    made it
  </div>
  <button data-bind="click: toggleObsProperty">Toggle Property</button>
</body>

</html>
```